# How to change array with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular ngTagsInput, when i use that output array is like below :

```
[{text: "4353453"}, {text: "453453"}, {text: "4534534"}, {text: "5345"}]
```

I want to remove `{"text" : " "}` in array with angular and array be a number list like `[234234,234234,234234,234]`

Comment: `arr.map(obj => +obj.text)`

Comment: or with ES5 `arr.map(function(obj) { return +obj.text; });`

Comment: thanks guys but how can i use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change or "Map" the array to produce the output you require by simply using the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. The results is a new array where the items from the array are replaced by the result of the anonymous callback. The callback method is passed the current item in the iteration.

```
var array = [{text: "4353453"}, {text: "453453"}, {text: "4534534"}, {text: "5345"}];

var new_array = array.map(function(item) {
 return parseInt(item.text);
});
console.log(new_array);//console will print [4353453, 453453, 4534534, 5345]
```

Comment: Whilst the code provided may (or may not) solve the OP.  It would greatly improve your answer if you were to provide some context and clarification of why you took this approach. Code without explaination is not always useful.

Comment: He want convert array of object to array of number and I've put some code to do it. I think it very simple and can try in browser's console. But thank, I will edit my answer

Comment: thanks but i got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`